# Calendar Control - Highlight Dates Programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar

I'm playing around with the calendar control and I can't seem to do the simple task of shading dates.  If the user enters 7 dates I want to shade those dates on the calendar so the user knows they have been selected.

Essentially I want do Calendar.HighlightDate("5/1/11") => imaginary lol I know this must be simple but I'm gong through the properties on MSDN and not finding anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the *ondayrender* event of the calendar object:

```
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" ondayrender="MyDayRenderer">
```

Then in your code behind, you can check the date and set the color:

```
   protected void MyDayRenderer(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Day.IsToday)
        {
            e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Aqua;
        }

        if (e.Day.Date == new DateTime(2011,5,1))
        {
            e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Beige;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry John I logged in and I simply saw the first answer, I've had a hectic week

Answer (score 2):

Here's some code I used on a project a LONG TIME ago. There may be a better way now. But this should work. The easiest way I could find was to dip into the DayRender event.

I used this to highlight certain days that were booked, pending, or available for a rental property.

```
protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < ar.Count; x++)
    {
        //if the date is in the past, just mark it as booked.
        if (e.Day.Date < DateTime.Now)
        {
            e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(38, 127, 0);
            e.Cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        }

        if (e.Day.Date.ToShortDateString() == Convert.ToDateTime(((ListItem)ar[x]).Text).ToShortDateString())
        {
            switch (((ListItem)ar[x]).Value)
            { 
                case "1":
                    e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(220,220,220);
                    break;
                case "2":
                    e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(38,127,0);
                    e.Cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                    break;
                case "3":
                    if (e.Day.IsWeekend)
                    {
                        e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255,255,204);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```